# How to automatically fill input field?

Tags: jsf

I have a page that shows a post where users can insert comments. When I create my comment I call my managedBean method `CommentsController.Create()` and everything works perfectly. But I have to specify the post id in the form. And I would like sent automatically fill the field postId since I know the postid of the current post.

I tried to fill the type of the input to hidden but it does not work ... and the user can very well change the value on the client side.

my form :

```
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
             ...
             //I want to fill this automatically...
            <h:selectOneMenu id="postId"
                             value="#{commentsController.selected.postId}" 
                             title="#{bundle.CreateCommentsTitle_postId}"
                             required="true"
                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateCommentsRequiredMessage_postId}"
                             >
                <f:selectItems value="#{postsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
           ...
           <h:commandLink action="#{commentsController.create}" 
                          value="#{bundle.CreateCommentsSaveLink}"
                          />
    </h:form>
```

My CommentsController:

```
public String create() {
    try {
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("CommentsCreated"));
        return "/posts/View.xhtml";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, the postId should automatically be send since you have `value="#{commentsController.selected.postId}"` So it is unclear to me what your actual problem is

Comment: In this case the user have to select the postId by himself... And I want to find a way to send to my controller the id of the post or get by another way and create my comment like this.

Comment: Keep it server side in a view-scoped bean? But a `h:inputHidden` should work as well. Or in a param in the action of the commandLink of

Comment: Yeah this worked with the inputHidden (thanks!) but I used the params in the commandLink. But the problems now is when I add my comment after redirect to my Post view -> return "/posts/View" the comment not appear... I need to restart build and clean and run the web app from netbean... I get the comments from my current posts with ```<ui:repeat value="#{postsController.selected.commentsCollection}" var="comment">```